What thickness wire should be used for 200-300 A?
I will be using a transformer from microwave. I won't change the primary coil so it will be about 130 turns.
My goal is to turn 230 V into 35-40 V and increase the current to 200-300 A.
How many turns should I use in the secondary coil and what size of wire should I use for secondary coil so it can hold those 200-300 A?
Transformator will be used only about 5-10min at a time.
And no I am not making a railgun.

Please show all dimensions of transformer, AWG turns and what you want to design to.

40 V and 300 A is 12 kW. What kind of industrial microwave are you taking apart?

If you're trying to make a rail gun, it's usual to store the energy in capacitors for each shot. Also, making a weapon may be subject to laws where you are.

A typical 230VAC outlet only supports 16A.  That's about 3700 watts.  You want (35Vx200A=7000 watts) at a minimum.  That will not work.  You are trying to get more power out than the outlet can deliver.

This doesn't answer your question, but a typical MO transformer has a magnetic shunt, which both gives load regulation, and reduces the coupling coefficient. Turns ratio calculations that work for tightly coupled transformers will give wrong results for poorly coupled transformers. Unless you need a shunt, you should remove it. You might need the shunt , for load regulation, for example if you are using the MOT for welding. Otherwise, remove.

Please edit the question to indicate the duty factor / duty cycle you will be operating the transformer at. It will drastically change the requirements for the wire. All wire gets hot during operation, but how hot it gets depends on how long it stays on at full current. And then the wire size will determine how well it can conduct and ultimately dissipate the heat. The upper limit is continuous operation. Anything less than that will let you use smaller diameter wire. A MOT will thermally run away when operated continuously at the power level you want anyway so continuous is not an option.

230V/40V = 5.75
If you have 130 turns on primary then you should use 130/5.75 = ~22.6 turns on the secondary (according to theory).
Reviewing the table here, you better be using larger than 4/0 (0000) cable and even then, at the amp levels you're describing, it'll get very very hot.
One other thing to check is what size cables are on the primary side. As winny mentioned, you're trying to convert 12kW. 12kW/230 ~= 52 Amps on the primary side. If your primary windings are not already 8 AWG according to the table, you should not be doing this.
Even if you build this, please be careful. This amount of power is no joke.
Another aspect I haven't analyzed is whether or not your current ferromagnetic core can handle the amount of magnetic flux you're trying to send through. If it wasn't designed for it, it probably won't work.

I've used 0000 copper wire. It doesn't bend easily-certainly not at small radius. It's tough enough to wrestle inside a junction box.

@Fred I don't envy you at all. Standard romex is annoying enough. I've messed with 6awg, but can't imagine playing with 0000 in a junction box.

Well I am talking about bigger junction boxes.

Based on your goal to generate 200 to 300 Arms using the AC line 230Vrms, you want to know what wire can support this using an MOT or Microwave Oven Transformer typically rated for a 1.5kW oven.
American Wire Guage (AWG) #0000 11.684 mm/ 2.17" diameter has an ampacity rating that increases with wire temperature of 195A/60C 230A/75C 260/90C.  Thus the tolerance of temperature rise above ambient determines the Ampacity and thus the wire gauge.
However, this does not mean you can transform 230V primary into 230 A secondary.
The power and impedance equations must be satisfied in an ideal lossless transformer.
V x Irms (both primary, p)  = V x Irms (both secondary, s)
Vp/Vs = n/1 turns ratio
Rp/Rs x n^2    (Equiv. Resistance load primary to secondary)
With 130 primary turns and 1 secondary turn, the lossless secondary voltage is 230V/130 = 1.77 V while the primary current would be 230A/130 = 1.76A
To get say 230 Amps, the wire and load resistance must be 7.7 mohms.  Recall #0000 AWG wire was the smallest wire to support this current at 75 deg. C and Wiki says its resistance is 0.1608 mohm/m. so you could not short out the wire and controlling the secondary current resistance and temperature may be difficult without some engineering specs for the type of load you choose and MOT efficiency.
MOT cores are welded, lowering efficiency from eddy current losses but making them acceptably quieter.
You must now determine how many turns of secondary 2.17" diameter wire you can wrap on an MOT core.  However, if your duty cycle is low then the temperature will not reach 75'C then you might use a smaller diameter wire to choose your secondary load resistance and voltage to satisfy your 230 Amp load.  If you were thinking of welding, almost shorting out your secondary no-load voltage, the plasma current would be very erratic and the turns ratio vs temperature must be adjusted with % duty factor of the current.
